# Laravel 5 can I train relationships while both relationships are in seperated models?

Tags: php, database, laravel, function, relationship

File structure:
- Project.php
- Tasklists.php

Project.php
Relationship: getTasklists();

```
public function getAllTasklists()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Tasklists', 'project_id')->orderBy('order', 'asc');
    }
```

Tasklists.php:
Relationship: getAllTasks();

```
  public function getAllTasks()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Task', 'tasklist_id');
  }
```

Now in the Project.php file I want to do the following:

```
$this->getAllTasklists()->getAllTasks();
```

But the second function getAllTasks() does not work because it doesn't "exists". And I did include the other model in this model.

Does anyone know on how to make this efficient as possible?

Comment: `$this->getAllTasklists()->getAllTasks();` It is only possible when you `getAllTasklists()` method will return the object of `Tasklists` class. But this is very bad solution.

Comment: You probably want `hasManyThrough`.

Comment: Change this: return $this->hasMany('App\Tasklists', 'project_id')->orderBy('order', 'asc') to: return $this->hasMany('App\Tasklists', 'project_id')->orderBy('order', 'asc')->with('getAllTasks');     Then in your Project.php file $this->getAllTasklists();